# Unicode literals in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, unicode, unicode-escapes, unicode-literals

Consider the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    std::string s = "\xe2\x82\xac\u20ac";
    std::ofstream out("test.txt");
    out << s.length() << ":" << s << std::endl;
    out << std::endl;
    out.close();
}
```

Under GCC 4.8 on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04), the file `test.txt` contains this:

```
6:€€
```

Under Visual C++ 2013 on Windows, it contains this:

```
4:€\x80
```

(By '\x80' I mean the single 8-bit character 0x80).

I've been completely unable to get either compiler to output a `€` character using `std::wstring`.

Two questions:

- What exactly does the Microsoft compiler think it's doing with the `char*` literal?  It's obviously doing something to encode it, but what is not clear.
- What is the right way to rewrite the above code using `std::wstring` and `std::wofstream` so that it outputs two `€` characters?

Comment: L"\x20ac\x20ac" The encoding of 8-bit strings on Windows is the ambient 8-bit code page, which is 1252 in the United States. You are using utf8. (You are also interpreting the output file as utf8 instead of 1252.)

Comment: A fair point - the "it contains this" on Windows is according to Notepad++ with the encoding set to UTF-8.

Comment: Hmmm, systeminfo gives both system and input locals as "en-gb;English (United Kingdom)", thought whether that's a UTF-8 locale or not it doesn't say.

Comment: There is no such thing as a UTF-8 locale. Code page 65001 (UTF-8) cannot be the active code page.

Comment: So what is "en_GB.utf8"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are using `\u20ac` which is a Unicode character literal in an ASCII string.

MSVC encodes `"\xe2\x82\xac\u20ac"` as `0xe2, 0x82, 0xac, 0x80,` which is 4 narrow characters. It essentially encodes `\u20ac` as 0x80 because it mapped the euro character to the standard [1252 codepage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)

GCC is converting the Unicode literal `/u20ac` to the 3-byte UTF-8 sequence `0xe2, 0x82, 0xac` so the resulting string ends up as `0xe2, 0x82, 0xac, 0xe2, 0x82, 0xac`.

If you use `std::wstring = L"\xe2\x82\xac\u20ac"` it gets encoded by MSVC as `0xe2, 0x00, 0x82, 0x00, 0xac, 0x00, 0xac, 0x20` which is 4 wide characters, but since you are mixing a hand-created UTF-8 with a UTF-16, the resulting string doesn't make much sense. If you use a `std::wstring = L"\u20ac\u20ac"` you get 2 Unicode characters in a wide-string as you'd expect.

The next problem is that MSVC's ofstream and wofstream always write in ANSI/ASCII. To get it to write in UTF-8 you should use `<codecvt>` (VS 2010 or later):

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <codecvt>

int main()
{
    std::wstring s = L"\u20ac\u20ac";

    std::wofstream out("test.txt");
    std::locale loc(std::locale::classic(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>);
    out.imbue(loc);

    out << s.length() << L":" << s << std::endl;
    out << std::endl;
    out.close();
}
```

and to write UTF-16 (or more specifically UTF-16LE):

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <codecvt>

int main()
{
    std::wstring s = L"\u20ac\u20ac";

    std::wofstream out("test.txt", std::ios::binary );
    std::locale loc(std::locale::classic(), new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::little_endian>);
    out.imbue(loc);

    out << s.length() << L":" << s << L"\r\n";
    out << L"\r\n";
    out.close();
}
```

Note: With UTF-16 you have to use a binary mode rather than text mode to avoid corruption, so we can't use `std::endl` and have to use `L"\r\n"` to get the correct end-of-line text file behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Am I right in thinking that GCC doesn't support std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>?

Comment: Minor correction:  "It encodes \u20ac as 0x80 because Unicode character U+20AC is in position 80 in code page 1252 ([see table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252))."

Comment: @Raymond - Excellent. Thanks for the clarification! I'll fix it.